# Simulator screen size for iPhone with iOS 6 Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

What is the actual size for IOS 6 IPHONE SIMULATOR
as when i m taking a screen shot of the screen  its coming as 320x480 pixels.
But I guess it should be 320x568 pixels.

Comment: You need select correct device in `Hardware > Device` menu.

Comment: Take into account that points and pixels are not the same. In a 3.5 inch retina display, 320x480 points are 640x960 pixels.

Answer (score 5):

iOS 6 simulator runs at 640×1136 display. The new iPhone 5 -along with the iPod Touch 5th generation- has only one big change in terms of web development: screen resolution. These devices have a wide 4″ screen, WDVGA (Wide Double VGA) 640×1136pixels, 326 DPI -Retina Display as Apple called it. These devices have the same width as iPhone 4/4S but 176 more pixels-height on portrait mode.

having a 640×1136 display puts the new iPhone on the wrong side of being able to claim the new iPhone has an HD display, though the quality of a Retina display may leave a question as to whether or not the phone is beyond HD. On a specs sheet the new iPhone will have a lower resolution display than competing devices, and that may hurt iPhone sales if Apple’s competition presses their advantage.

But for this you need select correct device in Hardware > Device menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it should not. 320x480 is default iPhone resolution without Retina display. You can change this in menu (Hardware) of you simulator. iPhone 4S Retina display resolution will be 640x960, and iPhone 5 (which comes ONLY with Retina display, so you can't have 320x568) will have 640x1136

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add an update for those of you running XCode 4.2 on Snow Leopard. If you want to run the simulator with the iPhone 5 resolution (and can't install newer versions of XCode), you can edit your Info.plist file for the iPhone 4 (Retina) to get the desired resolution.

To accomplish this, take the following steps

1. Edit your `Info.plist` file in
   `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone
   Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/Devices/iPhone
   (Retina).deviceinfo/`
2. Open the .plist file in XCode and add the following key/value pairs,

   - eagle : 640
   - giraffe:1136
3. Save the file and restart your simulator.
4. Select iPhone (Retina) to see the new resolution.

**Note**: there is one caveat -- the surrounding iPhone device "hardware" graphic will not scale to the new resolution.

Comment: I made the two changes and did not get an change in the simulator. Is there anything else you did beside adding eagle and giraffe?